# spring boot dev tools - how to enable auto start for an non IDE

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot, restart

I m in my early stage in learning spring boot. I am using the spring boot CLI and have a hello world groovy(app.groovy) file as below.

```
@RestController
class HelloApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String home() {
        "Hello!"
    }

}
```

I want to keep my development simple(without involving any IDE) because the app is going to be only few pages. How do i enable dev tools so that i can ftp the app.groovy file to the server when there is a change and i expect the change to be detected and the container is restarted without rerunning the following command.

```
spring.bat run app.groovy
```

Answer (score 2):

`spring run --watch app.groovy` will watch for changes to that file and restart the container.